# Extracting results from Android ZXing IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code, zxing

I am rather new to ZXing and has been exploring their API. 
I have seen [Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app) and [getting scan result when using zxing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504556/getting-scan-result-when-using-zxing)

I understand that  the details of the scan result is in the string "contents". How do I extract out the details? Looking at the QR generator, http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/ there are many fields like name, company and phone number. How do i extract these details?

I would need something like

```
//String extractedName = contents.getName()
```

Sorry, I am very new to this. I would appreciate if someone can provide me detailed steps. Thanks.

TestActivity

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MenuActivity.this);
}
};


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        // Handle successful scan
        //How to get name from contents?

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Handle cancel
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully extracted it. The scanned results is inside the string 'contents'. Lets say you scanned a code with name and id. The string will contain "name" "id" separated by a whitespace. You can use a for loop to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

> How do i extract these details?

A QR code is simply is a file in the form of a picture. Just as you need to know the format of a file before you can use it, you need to know the format of a QR code's contents before you can use it.

[This ZXing Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents) has information about the types of QR code contents that they have seen.

Comment: In particular use http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/client/result/ResultParser.java from the project to parse the raw content into a structured object.

Comment: Someone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

create object in IntentIntegrator

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { <br>
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br>
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);<br>
        new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();<br>
    }
```

Override onActivityResult method

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { <br>
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);<br>
        if (scanResult != null) {<br>
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);<br>
            String data[] =scanResult.getContents().split("\n");<br>
            for(String k:data){<br>
                t.append(k+"\n");<br>
            }<br>
        }<br>

        // else continue with any other code you need in the method

    }
```

In this I got data using getContents method and split that data line. Then appeded that data to the textview2

Answer (score 0):

first check the beginning of the string for example if it startsWith("xyxy") like "vcard". Be careful! "vcard" is not the correct string!

If it's a vCard i used to splitt it into Parts.

```
String[] vCardContent = content.split("\n");
```

Next Step is to check every part if it starts with e.g. "N:" alias "Name"