# CaptureActivity from Zxing library didn't return when barcode is scanned

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

i have integrated zxing library in my app, i used to call zxing via intent :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` allows user to choose scan app if he has another barcode scanners, and i want that if user starts scan from my app than will stats my zxing **CaptureActivity.class** , i call it via intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptuureActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But when Capture Activity detect barcode nothing happend, it didnt comes back to  previous activity .

Here is **CaptureACtivity :**

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = CaptureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

   private static final long DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 1500L;
    private static final long BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS = 1000L;
private static final String[] ZXING_URLS = { "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan", "zxing://scan/" };

public static final int HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000bacc;

private static final Collection<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES =
        EnumSet.of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER,
                ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
                ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
                ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);

private CameraManager cameraManager;
private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
private Result savedResultToShow;
private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
private TextView statusView;
private View resultView;
private Result lastResult;
private boolean hasSurface;
private boolean copyToClipboard;
private IntentSource source;
private String sourceUrl;
private ScanFromWebPageManager scanFromWebPageManager;
private Collection<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
private Map<DecodeHintType,?> decodeHints;
private String characterSet;
private HistoryManager historyManager;
private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
private BeepManager beepManager;
private AmbientLightManager ambientLightManager;

ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
    return viewfinderView;
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

CameraManager getCameraManager() {
    return cameraManager;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    hasSurface = false;
    historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
    historyManager.trimHistory();
    inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);
    beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
    ambientLightManager = new AmbientLightManager(this);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // CameraManager must be initialized here, not in onCreate(). This is necessary because we don't
    // want to open the camera driver and measure the screen size if we're going to show the help on
    // first launch. That led to bugs where the scanning rectangle was the wrong size and partially
    // off screen.
    cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());

    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);

    resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
    statusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);

    handler = null;
    lastResult = null;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

//    if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_DISABLE_AUTO_ORIENTATION, true)) {
//      setRequestedOrientation(getCurrentOrientation());
//    } else {
//      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

//    }

        resetStatusView();
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
        // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still exists. Therefore
        // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
        initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
        // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the camera.
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    beepManager.updatePrefs();
    ambientLightManager.start(cameraManager);

    inactivityTimer.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    copyToClipboard = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD, true)
            && (intent == null || intent.getBooleanExtra(Intents.Scan.SAVE_HISTORY, true));

    source = IntentSource.NONE;
    decodeFormats = null;
    characterSet = null;

    if (intent != null) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        String dataString = intent.getDataString();

        if (Intents.Scan.ACTION.equals(action)) {

            to the calling activity.
            source = IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(intent);
            decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(intent);


            if (intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH) && intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT)) {
                int width = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH, 0);
                int height = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT, 0);
                if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                    cameraManager.setManualFramingRect(width, height);
                }
            }

            String customPromptMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE);
            if (customPromptMessage != null) {
                statusView.setText(customPromptMessage);
            }

        } else if (dataString != null &&
                dataString.contains("http://www.google") &&
                dataString.contains("/m/products/scan")) {

            // Scan only products and send the result to mobile Product Search.
            source = IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.PRODUCT_FORMATS;

        } else if (isZXingURL(dataString)) {

            // Scan formats requested in query string (all formats if none specified).
            // If a return URL is specified, send the results there. Otherwise, handle it ourselves.
            source = IntentSource.ZXING_LINK;
            sourceUrl = dataString;
            Uri inputUri = Uri.parse(dataString);
            scanFromWebPageManager = new ScanFromWebPageManager(inputUri);
            decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(inputUri);
            // Allow a sub-set of the hints to be specified by the caller.
            decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(inputUri);

        }

        characterSet = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.CHARACTER_SET);

    }
}

private int getCurrentOrientation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        default:
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
    }
}

private static boolean isZXingURL(String dataString) {
    if (dataString == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String url : ZXING_URLS) {
        if (dataString.startsWith(url)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.quitSynchronously();
        handler = null;
    }
    inactivityTimer.onPause();
    ambientLightManager.stop();
    cameraManager.closeDriver();
    if (!hasSurface) {
       /* SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);*/
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    inactivityTimer.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            if ((source == IntentSource.NONE || source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK) && lastResult != null) {
                restartPreviewAfterDelay(0L);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            // Handle these events so they don't launch the Camera app
            return true;
        // Use volume up/down to turn on light
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            cameraManager.setTorch(false);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            cameraManager.setTorch(true);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.capture, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_share:
            intent.setClassName(this, ShareActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_history:
            intent.setClassName(this, HistoryActivity.class.getName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_help:
            intent.setClassName(this, HelpActivity.class.getName());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
            if (itemNumber >= 0) {

                HistoryItem historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);
                decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Result result) {
    // Bitmap isn't used yet -- will be used soon
    if (handler == null) {
        savedResultToShow = result;
    } else {
        if (result != null) {
            savedResultToShow = result;
        }
        if (savedResultToShow != null) {
            Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.decode_succeeded, savedResultToShow);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        savedResultToShow = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (holder == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** WARNING *** surfaceCreated() gave us a null surface!");
    }
    if (!hasSurface) {
        hasSurface = true;
        initCamera(holder);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

/**
 * A valid barcode has been found, so give an indication of success and show the results.
 *
 * @param rawResult The contents of the barcode.
 * @param scaleFactor amount by which thumbnail was scaled
 * @param barcode   A greyscale bitmap of the camera data which was decoded.
 */
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor) {
    inactivityTimer.onActivity();
    lastResult = rawResult;
    ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(this, rawResult);

    boolean fromLiveScan = barcode != null;
    if (fromLiveScan) {
        historyManager.addHistoryItem(rawResult, resultHandler);
        // Then not from history, so beep/vibrate and we have an image to draw on
        beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
        //drawResultPoints(barcode, scaleFactor, rawResult);
    }

    switch (source) {
        case NATIVE_APP_INTENT:
            handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            break;
        case PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK:
            handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            break;
        case ZXING_LINK:
            if (scanFromWebPageManager == null || !scanFromWebPageManager.isScanFromWebPage()) {
                handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);

            } else {
                handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            }
            break;
        case NONE:
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if (fromLiveScan && prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_BULK_MODE, false)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.msg_bulk_mode_scanned) + " (" + rawResult.getText() + ')',
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Wait a moment or else it will scan the same barcode continuously about 3 times
               // restartPreviewAfterDelay(BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS);
            } else {
                handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
            }
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Superimpose a line for 1D or dots for 2D to highlight the key features of the barcode.
 *
 * @param barcode   A bitmap of the captured image.
 * @param scaleFactor amount by which thumbnail was scaled
 * @param rawResult The decoded results which contains the points to draw.
 */
private void drawResultPoints(Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor, Result rawResult) {
    ResultPoint[] points = rawResult.getResultPoints();
    if (points != null && points.length > 0) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(barcode);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_points));
        if (points.length == 2) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1], scaleFactor);
        } else if (points.length == 4 &&
                (rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.UPC_A ||
                        rawResult.getBarcodeFormat() == BarcodeFormat.EAN_13)) {
            // Hacky special case -- draw two lines, for the barcode and metadata
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[0], points[1], scaleFactor);
            drawLine(canvas, paint, points[2], points[3], scaleFactor);
        } else {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
            for (ResultPoint point : points) {
                if (point != null) {
                    canvas.drawPoint(scaleFactor * point.getX(), scaleFactor * point.getY(), paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, ResultPoint a, ResultPoint b, float scaleFactor) {
    if (a != null && b != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(scaleFactor * a.getX(),
                scaleFactor * a.getY(),
                scaleFactor * b.getX(),
                scaleFactor * b.getY(),
                paint);
    }
}

// Put up our own UI for how to handle the decoded contents.
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {

    CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();

    if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
        ClipboardInterface.setText(displayContents, this);
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (resultHandler.getDefaultButtonID() != null && prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_AUTO_OPEN_WEB, false)) {
        resultHandler.handleButtonPress(resultHandler.getDefaultButtonID());
        return;
    }

    statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    /*ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
    if (barcode == null) {
        barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.launcher_icon));
    } else {
        barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);
    })*/

    TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
    formatTextView.setText(rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
    typeTextView.setText(resultHandler.getType().toString());

    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
    timeTextView.setText(formatter.format(new Date(rawResult.getTimestamp())));


    TextView metaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view);
    View metaTextViewLabel = findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view_label);
    metaTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Map<ResultMetadataType,Object> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
    if (metadata != null) {
        StringBuilder metadataText = new StringBuilder(20);
        for (Map.Entry<ResultMetadataType,Object> entry : metadata.entrySet()) {
            if (DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                metadataText.append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
            }
        }
        if (metadataText.length() > 0) {
            metadataText.setLength(metadataText.length() - 1);
            metaTextView.setText(metadataText);
            metaTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
    contentsTextView.setText(displayContents);
    int scaledSize = Math.max(22, 32 - displayContents.length() / 4);
    contentsTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, scaledSize);

    TextView supplementTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_supplement_text_view);
    supplementTextView.setText("");
    supplementTextView.setOnClickListener(null);
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(
            PreferencesActivity.KEY_SUPPLEMENTAL, true)) {
        SupplementalInfoRetriever.maybeInvokeRetrieval(supplementTextView,
                resultHandler.getResult(),
                historyManager,
                this);
    }

    int buttonCount = resultHandler.getButtonCount();
    ViewGroup buttonView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.result_button_view);
    buttonView.requestFocus();
    for (int x = 0; x < ResultHandler.MAX_BUTTON_COUNT; x++) {
        TextView button = (TextView) buttonView.getChildAt(x);
        if (x < buttonCount) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setText(resultHandler.getButtonText(x));
            button.setOnClickListener(new ResultButtonListener(resultHandler, x));
        } else {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}

// Briefly show the contents of the barcode, then handle the result outside Barcode Scanner.
private void handleDecodeExternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {

    if (barcode != null) {
        viewfinderView.drawResultBitmap(barcode);
    }

    long resultDurationMS;
    if (getIntent() == null) {
        resultDurationMS = 0;
    } else {
       resultDurationMS = getIntent().getLongExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS,
                0);
    }

    if (resultDurationMS > 0) {
        String rawResultString = String.valueOf(rawResult);
       if (rawResultString.length() > 32) {
            rawResultString = rawResultString.substring(0, 32) + " ...";
        }
        statusView.setText(getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()) + " : " + rawResultString);
   }

    if (copyToClipboard && !resultHandler.areContentsSecure()) {
        CharSequence text = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
        ClipboardInterface.setText(text, this);
    }

    if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {

        // Hand back whatever action they requested - this can be changed to Intents.Scan.ACTION when
        // the deprecated intent is retired.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT, rawResult.toString());
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);

        byte[] rawBytes = rawResult.getRawBytes();
        if (rawBytes != null && rawBytes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTES, rawBytes);
        }
        Map<ResultMetadataType,?> metadata = rawResult.getResultMetadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
            if (metadata.containsKey(ResultMetadataType.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION)) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_UPC_EAN_EXTENSION,
                        metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION).toString());
            }
            Number orientation = (Number) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.ORIENTATION);
            if (orientation != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ORIENTATION, orientation.intValue());
            }
            String ecLevel = (String) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL);
            if (ecLevel != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL, ecLevel);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Iterable<byte[]> byteSegments = (Iterable<byte[]>) metadata.get(ResultMetadataType.BYTE_SEGMENTS);
            if (byteSegments != null) {
                int i = 0;
                for (byte[] byteSegment : byteSegments) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_BYTE_SEGMENTS_PREFIX + i, byteSegment);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        sendReplyMessage(R.id.return_scan_result, intent, 0);

    } else if (source == IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK) {

        // Reformulate the URL which triggered us into a query, so that the request goes to the same
        // TLD as the scan URL.
        int end = sourceUrl.lastIndexOf("/scan");
        String replyURL = sourceUrl.substring(0, end) + "?q=" + resultHandler.getDisplayContents() + "&source=zxing";
        sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL, 0);

    } else if (source == IntentSource.ZXING_LINK) {

        if (scanFromWebPageManager != null && scanFromWebPageManager.isScanFromWebPage()) {
            String replyURL = scanFromWebPageManager.buildReplyURL(rawResult, resultHandler);
            sendReplyMessage(R.id.launch_product_query, replyURL, 0);
        }

    }
}

private void sendReplyMessage(int id, Object arg, long delayMS) {
    if (handler != null) {
        Message message = Message.obtain(handler, id, arg);
        if (delayMS > 0L) {
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, delayMS);
        } else {
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if (surfaceHolder == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No SurfaceHolder provided");
    }
    if (cameraManager.isOpen()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "initCamera() while already open -- late SurfaceView callback?");
        return;
    }
    try {
        cameraManager.openDriver(surfaceHolder);
        // Creating the handler starts the preview, which can also throw a RuntimeException.
        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats, decodeHints, characterSet, cameraManager);
        }
        decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, null);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.w(TAG, ioe);
        displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // Barcode Scanner has seen crashes in the wild of this variety:
        // java.?lang.?RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error initializing camera", e);
        displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    }
}

private void displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_camera_framework_bug));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new FinishListener(this));
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new FinishListener(this));
    builder.show();
}

public void restartPreviewAfterDelay(long delayMS) {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview, delayMS);
    }
    resetStatusView();
}

private void resetStatusView() {
    resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    statusView.setText(R.string.msg_default_status);
    statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lastResult = null;
}

public void drawViewfinder() {
        viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();
    }
}
```

I set `RESULT_OK` in

```
            if (source == IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT, rawResult.toString());
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
            ......
```

What im doing wrong?

And one more question , when i call scan with `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` when barcode was captured actvity didnt close immediately, it wait about 500-1000 milliseconds , how to disable this ?
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ***add the third line here*** while starting the intent, thats all, no need for any change in Zxing code, these guys Rock

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaptureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "QR_CODE,EAN_13,EAN_8,RSS_14,UPC_A,UPC_E,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,ITF,CODABAR,DATA_MATRIX");
        intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

By the way I'm using Zxing version 3.2.0

Just like to add the code that I used to receive the output from Zxing:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT);
        String formatName = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT);
        tvStatus.setText(formatName);
        tvScanResults.setText(contents + "\n\n" + formatName);
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
    }
}
```